# Enqueue Style for a page/pages only

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

it is causing problem because i did not do it before. I am trying to enqueue style or may be scripts depending on page. But it not working. Here is the code:

```
add_action('init', 'my_enqueue_styles');

function my_enqueue_styles(){
    if(is_page('Add Event')){ // also tried slug, page id and wp_reset_query(); bot not worked

    wp_deregister_style( 'jquery-ui-custom-flick' );
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-custom-flick', get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/styles/jquery.ui/ui.custom.flick.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-custom-flick' );
    }

}
```

I am not doing the conditional right. The script works without the conditional.

Thanks!

### **RESOLVED:**

The problem was with the `init` action hook. the conditional `is_page()` is false when `init` is called. After adding the style to the hook `wp_print_styles` it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *should* work like this.

Sidenotes: I don't know why you deregister a stylesheet and register it again. Also: `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` is now replaced by `get_template_directory_uri()`. Third: Are your folders really named with dots in between? Maybe this causes problems. And maybe your ui stylesheet is an dependency of the main jquery ui stylesheet.

**You should also start accepting answers on your questions. Your "accept rate" of 67% will people hold back from answering your Qs.**

```
function wpse_16487_enqueue_styles()
{
    if ( is_page('Add Event') ) // also tried slug, page id and wp_reset_query(); bot not worked
    { 
        wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-custom-flick', get_template_directory_uri().'/styles/jquery-ui/ui-custom-flick.css', 'jquery-ui' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-custom-flick' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'wpse_16487_enqueue_styles' );
```

If something's not working, you should start debugging your wp query: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']); echo '</pre>';` and check for the page name/slug to register it.

Comment: Thanks for the `get_template_directory_uri();` tips :) and directory name with dot won't cause any problems. As i said the code works fine if i don't use the conditional `is_page();`. I guess `is_page()` is false when wordpress running the functions.php file. So the style not adding.

Comment: Worked! The problem was with the `init` action hook. the conditional is false when `init` is called. After adding the style to `wp_print_styles` it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear. Gald it worked.